# Bandwidth usage relates queries

Tags: c#, cloud, hyper-v

We wanted to get the bandwidth usage of hyper-v i.e total amount of data moved in and out of the network and it should calculate it according to the specific period(for example like from specific start time to specific end time,etc).Can u please suggest us any apis in C# or any links?

Waiting for reply....